# Count total number of data except status is pending

Tags: sql, count

Good day Guys. If the status of the transaction is PENDING it should not be considered counted how can I do this guys the sql syntax below is count all the data.

```
ELSE IF @TableName = 'Retail.MiscReceipt'
        BEGIN
            SET @WholeSelect = --@WholeSelect + @Operator + 
                    'SELECT '''+@TransType+''' AS TransType, UserName AS AddedBy, COUNT(*) AS Count ' +
                    'FROM '+@TableName+' AS TRN ' +
                    'LEFT JOIN IT.Users ON TRN.AddedBy = UserID ' +
                    'WHERE ISNULL(TRN.PostedBy,'''') = '''' AND LiquidationDate BETWEEN ''' + CONVERT(varchar(10),@DateFr) + ''' AND ''' + CONVERT(varchar(10),@DateTo) + ''''
        END
```

Comment: You would add `status <> 'PENDING'` . . . is there a reason this doesn't work?

Comment: how can i put it in my code?

Comment: A few questions:  a. AddedBy = UserID --> what is UserId here ( I have a gut feeling this might need to be a variable `@UserID` maybe)  b. Why convert the date values to varchar and then use in a date function?  c. PostedBy can be NULL or an empty string? Is there an inconsistency with that field's value?

Comment: the problem in this query sir if the status is pending it will not count into reportviewer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to change this line:

```
 'WHERE ISNULL(TRN.PostedBy,'''') = '''' AND LiquidationDate BETWEEN ''' + CONVERT(varchar(10),@DateFr) + ''' AND ''' + CONVERT(varchar(10),@DateTo) + ''''
```

to:

```
 'WHERE trn.status <> ''Pending'' AND ISNULL(TRN.PostedBy,'''') = '''' AND LiquidationDate BETWEEN ''' + CONVERT(varchar(10),@DateFr) + ''' AND ''' + CONVERT(varchar(10),@DateTo) + ''''
```

Comment: Quick question, how did you know the TRN table had a status field?

Comment: @RamRS . . . I don't.  I'm guessing based on the question:  "status of the transaction is . . .".

Comment: Yeah, I have a few questions too, OP needs to give more details, at least the schema of the table(s) involved.

Comment: @RamRS . . . I should add that I answered this in a comment because there wasn't enough information to provide a real answer.  The OP requested more detail on what the code would look like.

Comment: I understand. I'm just saying that the question itself needs more detail and OP should provide it, cuz it makes answering a tedious task otherwise.

Comment: Status is in TRN table .

Comment: @Renats: You mean in `Retail.MiscReceipt`, or in any table that might be "referenced" by @TableName?

Comment: in Retail.MiscReceipt.